# Format a string date in Freemarker

Tags: string, date, freemarker

How can I format a string date like `01282020` to `Jan 28, 2020` in Apache Freemarker?"

So the variable now displays as `<p>${date}</p>` whereas I would want to format the content of `date`

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts, I got this to work with `<p>${date?date("MMddyyyy")</p>`